# Prevent Laravel Hamcrest polluting global namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, hamcrest

Currently Laravel 5.5 includes hamcrest/hamcrest-php v1.2.2 by default.  According to my error logs, hamcrest is polluting the php global namespace with functions like `is()`.

> [Wed Jan 17 15:50:14.130470 2018] [php7:error] [pid 30809] [client 70.178.240.6:62075] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare is() (previously declared in /[censored]/laravel/vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php:306) in /[censored]/functions.php on line 2603

Shouldn't a library such as this be namespaced?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show us the package GitHub? and when did error happened?

Comment: https://github.com/hamcrest/hamcrest-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespaced static methods instead of global functions:

```
use Hamcrest\MatchersAssert as h;
use Hamcrest\Matchers as m;

h::assertThat(array(), m::anArray());
```

To remove the global functions you'll need to find and remove/comment out where they are declared. The declaration to remove is likely to be in one of three forms:

1. `require vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php` or
2. `Hamcrest\Util::registerGlobalFunctions();` or
3. The following lines in composer.json

   `"autoload-dev": {
     "files": ["vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php"]
   }`

The downside of using namespaced static methods instead of global functions is that `h::assertThat()` is slightly less pithy than `assertThat()` bearing in mind that one of the attractions of using Hamcrest is that test code is cleaner and simpler.

A more detailed discussion about this can be found at https://github.com/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/issues/45.